# How can I see what DNS requests are being made by a website?

Tags: linux, dns, request, debian, hosts

I recently generated a unified hosts file from Steven Black's [hosts github project](https://github.com/StevenBlack/hosts) on my MX Linux machine. However, it's preventing cbs.com from loading their sponsored messages. This, in turn, is preventing the actual content from loading. I need to whitelist the domain for their ads, or at least remove it from my hosts file.

I am wondering if there is a way to see/monitor what DNS requests are made by a website that I'm visiting. I simply need to figure out what server CBS is reaching out to for their ads, so that I can ensure they're able to.

Comment: "I am wondering if there is a way to see/monitor what DNS requests are made by a website that I'm visiting. " Open the Web Developer Tools in your browser and see all resources loaded and hence what names are resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a great way to do this by using dnstop. It can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install dnstop
```

Then you need the network interface name for the device you want to listen to. You can see a list of these interfaces with this command:

```
ip link show
```

The name following the listing number is what you need. This will be something like "eth0" or "wlan0". Once you know the interface name, run this command:

```
dnstop {interface-name}
```

With the interface you want to listen to. Once dnstop starts, press the number **2** on your keyboard to view a list and running tally of requests made.

Comment: This won't work for browsers using DNS over HTTPS for their resolution. Which is more and more the case...